# How to set alarm at next day if chosen time already gone

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarmmanager

How to set alarm at next day if chosen time already gone? 
I got method, where I set alarm, but if that time has already gone it just happens now. I need, to enable this alarm at next day. How can I change this code? 'cuz this code doesn't work: alarm goes right now

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    long until = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_HOUR_1, selected_hour_1));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_MINUTE_1, selected_minute_1));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long seted = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SetVolume_1.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 23, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, seted, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, seted, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Oh... I forgot this

Comment: if (seted >= now){
            long left = until - now;
            long doit = seted + left;
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, doit, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, seted, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple, as you have a calendar instance for when you want the alarm to be set, just get its time in millis and compare it to now, if it is bigger then the time is yet to be reached, else you just need to add a day to that same calendar. The implementation is pretty straightforward i think :).

**EDIT**
I actually had to do something similar and here is my code, you can adapt it however you need and it should help you understand this problem.

```
fun setAlarm(context: Context, interval: Long) {
    val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val i = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) //Flag Update Current FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

    val prefTime = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(SettingsValues.NOTIFICATION_TIME_KEY, "1").toInt()
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, prefTime)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    var time = calendar.timeInMillis
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > time) {
        time = time + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // Next day
    }
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            time , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    isActive = true
}
```

**IMPORTANT** If you take a look at how i am using the calendar instance your answear should be there. if now is after the Calendar total time in millis i add a full day.

Comment: look there goo.gl/wWgLqY

Answer (score 0):

To set the alarm for the following day, you would add this when setting your time:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

To easily check if the time has already passed that day, and only set it for the next day if it has passed, check it like this:

```
 if(calendar.before(System.currentTimeMillis())){
 calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 }
```

This will only set the calendar time to the following day if the time that was set has passed on the current day.